# Updating Label on Button Click

Tags: swift3, uibutton, uilabel, xcode8, ios10

I have two buttons as right and left arrow on my main page and every time a button is clicked UILabel is updated through an array e.g `let names = ["John, Smith, "Ahmed", "Jack", "Kathy"]`. I have two UIActions as rightArrowClicked and leftArrowClicked. Initially the label should appear as John with left arrow disabled, which'll be done by the isHidden property of leftArrow and likewise when the value is Kathy then rightArrow should be disabled. Along with that i also need to update another label w.r.t to the name value e.g john can have a value of "cute", and kathy as "pretty" and these values are coming from an external library which i've added via `cocoapods` which are being generated in a function of that class. Any ideas how would i do that?

Comment: Better to use Collection View, Add one label in Collection cell(which is equal width to Collection View) and set names label and right and left button click you use scroll to index method

Comment: No @Narayana collectionView is not the solution to what i am talking about.

Comment: I have added my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is code with simple logic that you need

```
let names = ["John", "Smith", "Ahmed", "Jack", "Kathy"]
var currentIndex = 0
leftButton.isHidden = true

@IBAction func left(_ sender: Any) {
    currentIndex --
    label.text = names[currentIndex]

    if currentIndex == 0 {
        leftButton.isHidden = true
    }

    rightButton.isHidden = false


}

@IBAction func right(_ sender: Any) {
    currentIndex ++
    label.text = names[currentIndex]

    if currentIndex == names.count - 1 {
        rightButton.isHidden = true
    }

    leftButton.isHidden = false

}
```

Comment: Thanks, I implemented your answer and its working but the right button is not being hidden on the last index i.e kathy, p.s the main concern is the values which are coming through the library corresponding to the name values they also need to be updated w.r.t to the namevalue.

Comment: @UsamabinAttique Oops I made a mistake. See the updated code. the count is 1 greater than the index

Comment: what about the corresponding value for each array index coming from the library. they need to change with the button as well. how would i handle them?

Comment: @UsamabinAttique Use the `currentIndex` because that get increased & decreased as you click on left or right buttons

Answer (score 0):

You can try like below and call updateButtonsState() in viewDidLoad method

```
let names = ["John", "Smith", "Ahmed", "Jack", "Kathy"]
let nature = ["cute", "pretty", "cute", "pretty", "cute"]
var currenIndex = 0

@IBAction func leftBtnClick(_ sender: UIButton) {
        currenIndex = currenIndex - 1
        updateButtonsState()

    }
    @IBAction func rignthBtnClick(_ sender: UIButton) {
        currenIndex = currenIndex + 1
        updateButtonsState()
    }
    func updateButtonsState() {
        leftBtn.isEnabled = currenIndex > 0 ? true : false
        rightBtn.isEnabled = currenIndex < names.count - 1 ? true : false
        if currenIndex >= 0 && currenIndex < names.count {
            lblName.text = names[currenIndex]
            lblNameWithNature.text = nature[currenIndex]
        }
        print("currenIndex == \(currenIndex)")
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for your respone @Narayana but nature values are coming from the library and they can't be embedded in an array. they are returned via Nslog like "NSLog("John's Value%@", formatter.string(from: abc.xxxx))" 
"NSLog("KathysValue%@", formatter.string(from: abc.xxxx))"where abc is the variable with the initializer which takes in three four parameters.  and this is in a function which doesn't have a return type and i won't bother altering that because like i said its a library i've installed which performs tons of calculations on the backend to generate these values.

Comment: This is the core problem tbh. I could've done the other task in some time which is quite trivial in front of this.

Comment: @UsamabinAttique But that is your app logic that all can not be solved in stack overflow and now your requirement is not related to this question.